# jquery location.pathname

Tags: jquery

I would like to hide #workspace when url is:

http://machine/_l/R/bases.aspx#bases=0

http://machine/_l/R/bases.aspx#bases=1

http://machine/_l/R/bases.aspx#bases=2

and i would like to keep #workspace when url is

http://machine/_l/R/bases.aspx

i have tried that script below but that doesn't work!

```
var url = location.pathname;
if (url.indexOf('#bases=') >= 0) {
    //inner column width
    jQuery('#workspace').css('display', 'none');
}
```

any ideas?
thanks and happy friday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check `location.hash` instead of `location.pathname`